# Patterns to get a subset based on certain criteria (In Design)

Tags: design-patterns, oop, criteria, subset

I'm looking for a pattern for this general case:

"I need to get a subset of data based on directly related criteria and indirectly related data."

Comment: What more do you want?  You named the pattern: "get a subset".  What do you need to do once you've named the pattern?  What more help do you need?  Do you want the name of related patterns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Martin Fowler and Eric Evans's Specification Pattern ([pdf](http://martinfowler.com/apsupp/spec.pdf)) ([wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specification_pattern)) seems to fit your requirement.

Comment: Thanks guys, this was the sort of thing I was looking for. :)